# IOS Google Drive SDK API to download the file data

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I integrated google drive with my ios app. But whenever I try to select any file to download, the download url ends with **&gd=true**. I do not know what is that last part **"&gd=true"**. When I remove that string and try to download the file content, it was works fine. Also, when I include that, I'm not able to download the file content. Is it a google bug or something I am missing?

- loganathan

Comment: got this? i am stuck here

Comment: @preetam yeah it worked for me!!!! what error are you seeing?.

Comment: yes, I also did this now..no problem now. thx for attention.